# No suitable driver found error while starting hive and spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hadoop2

When i am trying to start hive or spark i am getting this error.

```
16/07/13 16:55:12 ERROR Schema: Failed initialising database.
No suitable driver found for jdbc:;derby;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusDataStoreException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:;derby;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
```

I am not able to resolve it.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

looks like hive lib path is not set in `spark-env.sh` file. Follow these steps

- Copy `hive-site.xml` from `HIVE_HOME/conf` to `SPARK_HOME/conf` folder.
- Add hive lib path to classpath in `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`
- Restart the Spark cluster for everything to take effect.

In order to setup mysql as hive metastore `hive-site.xml` should have these properties setup:

```
    <property>
     <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
     <value>jdbc:mysql://MYSQL_HOST:3306/hive_{version}</value>
     <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
     <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
     <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore/description>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
     <value>XXXXXXXX</value>
     <description>Username to use against metastore database/description>
    </property> 
    <property>
     <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
     <value>XXXXXXXX</value>
     <description>Password to use against metastore database/description>
    </property>
```

*if this does not resolve the error, provide more info about steps you follow to install/configure youe environment*

Comment: I am unable to start hive also using derby database.

Comment: can you tell us `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` value from `hive-site.xml` and values of environment variables - `HIVE_HOME, DERBY_HOME, PATH, and CLASSPATH` ? - copy paste this info in you question.

Comment: Initially when i installed hive there is no hive-site.xml file and when i am trying to open hive shell it is returning the above error now i have configured hive using mysql metastore. Now i am able to open hive shell but when i am trying to open spark-shell i am getting the above error.

Comment: you need to copy `hive-site.xml` that you created/modified in order to configure for mysql metasotre to `SPARK_HOME/conf` folder - to let spark know about hive configuration or else spark uses the defaults

Comment: After doing that i am getting this error :: Error creating transactional connection factory javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory...Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.DatastoreDriverNotFoundException: The specified datastore driver ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver...I have added the jdbc mysql connector jar also in spark_lib folder.

Comment: see my updated answer: Mysql properties must be set in `hive-site.xml` file. and make sure you have mysql connector jar in `HIVE_HOME/lib` and also added to the `CLASSPATH`

Comment: My hive-site.xml is also the same and mysql connector jar is present in HIVE_HOME/lib and SPARK_HOME/lib still i am getting the error. Tell me how you have added the HIVE_HOME/lib to spark-env.sh file.

Comment: ok in `saprk-env.sh` set `SPARK_HOME`, in $SPARK_HOME/conf/classpath.txt` add line of mysql connector jar with fully qualified and than start `spark-shell` . (with out seeing your actual configuration its hard to tell that what is causing this error)

Comment: Thanks! solved the issue by adding SPARK_CLASSPATH=/path_to_jar in spark-env.sh file.